# Receiver not registered error

Tags: android

**I have a bluetooth app which worked fine,in which i created a broadcast receiver and i also destroy  it on `onDestroy()` method but  when i pressed the back button on my cell phone it show unfortunately your app has stopedd and in the android monitor window it shows**

**[Receiver not registered][1]**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

            BA=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
           filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
           registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }    //onCreat End

    public void turnOn(View v)
    {
        if(!BA.isEnabled())
        {
               Intent turnOn=new Intent(BA.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
               startActivityForResult(turnOn, 1);
               Toast.makeText(this,"Turned On",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
               Toast.makeText(this,"Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void turnOff(View v)
    {
               BA.disable();

    }

    public void getVisible(View v)
    {
              Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
              startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
    }

    public void getList(View v)
      {
              pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
              ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
              list.add(bt.getName()+"\n"+bt.getAddress());

              ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
              lv.setAdapter(adapter);
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

              {
                  TextView v = (TextView) view;

              }
          });
        }
    public void exitApp(View v)
    {
           //   finish();

        System.exit(0);

    }

    public void getDiscoveredDevices(View v)   // onclick is in XML
    {
              // BA.startDiscovery();

        if(BA.isDiscovering())
        {
            BA.cancelDiscovery();

        }

       else {

            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device Discovery On",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,30);
            toast.show();
                       BA.startDiscovery();
            mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() //// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
            {
                ArrayList listt = new ArrayList();
                // Register the BroadcastReceiver


                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                          String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))  // // When discovery finds a device
                    {

                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);// Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                        listt.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listt);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,20);
                        toast.show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Device Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,20);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }

            };

              IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);



        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
       this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();

    }

} 
} //Class End
```

Comment: Can you cause the crash while connected with ADB and provide the exception stack trace?

Comment: Can you run your app from your IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio), press the back button on your device so that your app crashes, copy the log of the error reported to your IDE and paste it here?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.mortagraan.ledonoff.DeviceList$2@30d92951

Comment: too much pic, please use the code formatting tool instead of inserting a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BroadcastReceiver mReceiver` is not initialized before `registerReceiver` in the `onCreate`, `mReceiver` is null when you register it. Although you create it later in `getDiscoveredDevices` but it did not registered there. As for that, you try to unregister a receiver which is actually never been registered.
 So first create your receiver then register it not vica versa.

Comment: now i initalized it in oncreate method and register it in getDiscoveredDevices but again it show me an error and say     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent

Comment: please post your full stack trace with this exception

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.mortagraan.ledonoff.DeviceList$1@49b4e78
                                                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:943)

Comment: this would be the full trace ?

Comment: this seems to be  just a few row from the stack trace, please post the full stack trace in you qustion

Comment: Thank you  so much...sir it worked now fine..... i just initialized it in the main field and in the getDiscovered method i register it.....thank you sir so muchhh

Comment: Then please accept my answer if it was helpful for you