# Android: Internet BroadcastReceiver for the application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

In my application I need not to allow the user to use the app if there is no internet connection. I know there are a bunch of good tutorials out there to do this, but non has actually fulfilled the requirements I need.

The internet connection should be checked all time in the app. That's why, and based on [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#context-registered_receivers) part of the documentation, I registered my receiver in the `Application` class. However, the problem was **where to unregister the receiver**, since there are no `onDestort(), onStop()` methods in the class.

The other option I tried is to (un)register the receiver in my `BaseActivity` class which extends `AppCompatActivity` and all other activities in the app extends the `BaseActivity`, but I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered`

Lots of questions were solved by unregistering the receiver in `onStop()` if it was registered in `onStart()`, or to unregister it in `onDestroy()` if it was registered in `onCreate()`, but that didn't work for me as well.

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public interface ConnectivityChangedListener {
        void onConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected);
    }

    public static ConnectivityChangedListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (listener != null) {
            Log.i("Connectivity", "" + isConnected);
            listener.onConnectivityChanged(isConnected);
        }
    }
}
```

My BaseActivity.java (Other activities extend this one)

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityChangedListener {

    private static BroadcastReceiver br;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        br = new ConnectivityReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        ConnectivityReceiver.listener = this;

        registerReceiver(br, filter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        Log.i("Connectivity", "Activity " + isConnected);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244581/receiver-not-registered-error

Comment: @SunilP Will, that solved the problem. Thank you.
One other question, is the approach I'm using good for performance? I mean (un)registering receiver in the BaseActivity

Comment: yeah it should allow you

Answer (score 0):

> However, the problem was where to unregister the receiver, since there
>   are no onDestort(), onStop() methods in the class.

1. You can create a service and create an inner broadcast receiver class that will do the above work. In the `onDestroy()` method of the service you can unregister the receiver. Register in the `onCreate()` method of the service.

The advantage of this is that you can perform some long operation because a broadcast receiver will just execute the code inside `onReceive()` and exit away, say if you want to start any service or do other work that takes time then putting inside service is the best.

I guess other than that there is no place you could put it elsewhere.

2. Create a static method in broadcast receiver in a Application class like this,

   static ConnectionReceiver mConnectionReceiver;
   static Context appContext;
   static void registerConReceiver()
   {
       mConnectionReceiver = new ConnectionReceiver();
       IntentFilter filter = new   IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
   appContext.registerReceiver(mConnectionReceiver,filter);
   }

Then unregister whenever you want

```
static void unregisterConReceiver()
    {
        try{
             appContext.unregisterReceiver(mConnectionReceiver);
            mConnectionReceiver=null;
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            mConnectionReceiver = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: And how can I update the view on my activity? How can I prevent navigating to the MainActivity (from SplashActivity for example) if the connection is not available?

Comment: @MotassemJalal `How can I prevent navigating to the MainActivity (from SplashActivity for example) if the connection is not available?`

Use the above logic and `finish` the SplashActivity if the internet connection is not there

Comment: When using callbacks (as in MVP design pattern) the BroadcastReceiver is returning the result when the SplashActivity is already done. What I need is not to go to MainActivity if theere is no connection

Comment: @MotassemJalal  - You will then need to have a deciding activity from where you will decide whether you want to go to mainactivity or not.